# PCL ROS and system install clashing?

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Compiling [object_recognition_tabletop](https://github.com/wg-perception/tabletop) from source on Hydro throws lots of warning like this one:

```
CMake Warning at object_recognition_tabletop/src/db/CMakeLists.txt:2 (add_library):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target tabletop_db because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

runtime library [libpcl_common.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_kdtree.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_octree.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_search.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_io.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_sample_consensus.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_filters.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_visualization.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_outofcore.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_features.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_segmentation.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_people.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_registration.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_recognition.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_keypoints.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_surface.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib
runtime library [libpcl_tracking.so.1.7] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
  /opt/ros/hydro/lib

Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76813/pcl-ros-and-system-install-clashing?/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@vincent-rabaud found out the cause. I'll just quote him:

> You still have the ros-hydro-pcl package. You should remove it since that is now a system dependecy (hence in /usr/lib). It is not even part of the Hydro distribution anymore (as of 2 weeks ago)

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1